# F# Interactive faster than compiled

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I recently noticed that F# Interactive is much faster than the compiled version (in either Release or Debug mode). Here is an example:

```
let rec fib n = if n < 3 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

[<EntryPoint>]
let rec main argv = 
    let w = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    w.Start()
    fib 45
    w.Stop()
    printfn "%d" w.ElapsedMilliseconds
    System.Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

When compiled in release mode then run this outputs "12784", when run in F# Interactive it outputs "4986". I am running it in Interactive mode using "main [||];;".

Something weird is definitely going on, but I have no idea what!

**EDIT [Specs]:** F# 3.0 for .NET 4. The optimize code and generate tail call flags are set and I am compiling for x86. I am running this on an i7 950. I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: What are your F#/.NET framework/Visual Studio versions? Is the compiled version x86 or x64? Did you run the compiled program outside VS?

Comment: Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714588.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I really should have put my specs in, very stupid of me.

F# 3.0 for .NET 4. The optimize code and generate tail call flags are set and I am compiling for x86. I am running this on an i7 950. I am using visual studio 2012.

Comment: Try calling fib 3 before w.Start(). Maybe it has something to do with jitting and other startup code generation. I'm guessing fsi and the compiled version may do it at different times.

Comment: Just to confirm, you run the program outside Visual Studio, don't you? In this way, CLR JIT can perform some JIT optimizations.

Comment: I added a call to "fib 5" and it sped up computation somewhat. Then I tried executing the compiled exe outside of VS2012... I had no idea one had to do that (I don't use .NET much)! It sped it up a lot, but its still slightly slower than the interpreted version: "5709" vs "4986".

PS: I'm assuming F# interactive is interpreted.

Comment: F# interactive is compiled, just a bit differently.

Comment: Now they're comparable. If you compile the program to F# 3.0/.NET 4.5, I would expect their performance to be the same.

Comment: Under mono I get almost identical numbers for fsi and compiled - so this is probably a something to do with the .Net jit (mono v2.10.2 as well as today's git)

Comment: I can confirm they are almost exactly the same under .NET 4.5. Mystery solved! Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, it was a bit unfair to compare a .NET 4.0 program (compiled) and a .NET 4.5 program (interactive).

Comment: @Maltic - please post this as an answer for anyone who has the same issue in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran executable outside of VS2012 as suggested by pad, then changed to .NET 4.5. This equalized the run times.

Comment: To achieve the same effect as running executable outside VS, you can go to *Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General* and UNCHECK *Suppress JIT optimization on module load*.

Comment: Or just hit ctrl-f5 (menu: DEBUG/Start Without Debugging) instead of f5.

Answer (score -1):

Please see my answer : [What makes this F# so slow in VS2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250824/what-makes-this-f-so-slow-in-vs2012/19651820#19651820)

you have to add Fsharp.core.dll file to your exe file to make it load faster.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer